# value in Sheets.Range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm beginner. How can I use value in method Sheets("").Range("").Select
My code is below.

```
Dim value As String
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("B2").Select
value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("B2").value

Sheets("Welding").Select
Sheets("Welding").Range(value & "50";value & "61").Select
```

Comment: Can you add some more details, like what you hope to acheive, what is `value` likely to be a column letter?  Do you want to select 2 cells or from and to?

Comment: replace `;` with `:` in your last line.

Answer (score 0):

### Columns'n'Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColumnsnRows()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Arkusz1")
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range("B2")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Welding")
    Dim dCol As String: dCol = sCell.value
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Rows("50:61").Columns(dCol)
    ' You probably meant to use:
    'Set drg = dws.Range(dCol & "50:" & dCol & "61")
    
    ' Continue using 'drg'...
    
    ' You usually don't need to select, but if you do, you have to make sure
    ' that the worksheet is active.
    If Not dws Is ActiveSheet Then
        dws.Activate
    End If
    drg.Select
    ' Print the address in the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G'):
    'Debug.Print drg.Address
    ' Or:
    'drg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    'drg.Font.Bold = True
    'drg.Copy
    
End Sub
```